# LaTeX document errors where no errors exist

Tags: reference, latex

I am writing my thesis with LaTeX and since today very curious errors turn up. I wrote something and made a citication in the file references.bib, and then the errors turned up. Befor writing that few lines everything worked great. Thus, I deleted everything I've added. But the errors still turn up. One Error is: Extra }, or forgotten $. ...ckoverflow Permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW}. I think my citication (which I've deleted after the errors turned up) is still stored somewhere , because "ckoverflow Permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" was a part of the title of the cite. 
I hadn't found any error in any file. 
The next weird thing is that a mate of mine can compile that files without any problems. He is using WinEdt. I am using TeXStudio, but I've tried it with WinEdt, too. 

There is a screenshot of my errors:
[image]

Please help me, any suggestions are appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: It’s **impossible** to say from your description what causes the error. However, chances are you didn’t actually delete everything relevant. You probably have no old version you can revert to? At any rate, your description is wrong: clearly, there *is* an error in your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need to escape your `_` characters there, as they are normally used for subscript, but only in math mode; hence the "missing `$` inserted".

(La)TeX error messages make me sad... :(

Comment: I only have the underscore in my `lstlisting`, and there it should make no problem. It's not even possible to set the character `\` bevore the underscore in `lstlisting` because everything is printed as code then. And the error message where the `_` turns up was a citication which is already deleted.

Comment: Your comment appears garbled, use backticks (`) to surround special characters and render them in a code font. If you get errors about things that have already been deleted, try to remove the intermediate files generated by bibtex et al.

Comment: which ones are the intermediate files generated by bibtex?

Comment: Don't remember; I would basically delete everything that I didn't write myself :)

Comment: Thank you, I deleted everything I didn't write myself and now it is working well again. Thank you for your recommendation, I should had tried that before writing my problem here :)