# Overleaf/Latex: No Errors, good job! + Fatal Syntax Errors

Tags: latex, syntax-error, bibtex, biblatex, overleaf

This isn't a very big problem, but it's really annoying. I couldn't find any similar question (actually only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458989/latex-document-errors-where-no-errors-exist), but with no clear answers, sadly), therefore I decided to put this here.

I've been working on my master's thesis in **Overleaf**, I'm a longtime user and I try to be pretty careful about my code, and I never leave a report with syntax errors, or "badnesses" as Latex likes to call them. I was working on this two days ago, on a Windows machine, there were no errors, no badness of any kind, everything worked and I double-checked everything.

Today, on my Linux/Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I tried modifying some small things (nothing to do with any packages or syntax, it was just plain text modifications) and then **suddenly my references stopped working entirely**.
As I guess anyone who's sick and tired of Latex' No-Reason Errors would do, I deleted everything bibliography related and re-typed it all. So, the references are working again, the document compiles fine, but it still gives me this confusing bipolar message:

[No Errors, good job! + Fatal Syntax Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tok5t.png)

*(I still don't have the right to include images in questions, so that's why there's an external link to the image.)*

But also, I don't have much experience with bibliographies and citing, so I guess that is where the problems originated from. But even with deleting and re-typing it all from scratch, recreating the **.bib** file and all... This still comes up. I'm pretty much OCD and I would really want to fix it, and not see it coming up.

You can see all of my **TEX** code, the **.bib** file and the **Raw Logs** [here](https://github.com/7ovana/Rapport_Alternance), on my *GitHub* profile.

Has anybody had this problem before ?
Sorry for the rant, any suggestion, idea or a thought is more then welcomed.

*PS: Hope this Covid crisis ends soon, I hope you're all fine during these crazy times.*

Comment: Your document compiles without errors and also your log file does not show any errors. This seems like a problem of overleaf and not latex. I suggest to contact the overleaf support.